# switching to parent view controller on changing the tab from one tab to another

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, uitabbarcontroller, tabbarcontroller

In my application after logging in I am presenting a tab bar with four tabs in it and my question if how to come back to the parent view of first tab every time when my app comes from background to foreground

Comment: Have you created some navigation hierarchy for your tabs?

Comment: @user1184202 - Also consider the comment mentioned by Antonio MG.

Comment: yes i did created the navigation hierarchy

Comment: self.mybaseTabbarController.selectedIndex = 0;
    [self.mybaseTabbarController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];     
am trying like this to get back to parent view but still it didn't any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

```
YourAppDelegate *appdelegate = ((YourAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]);

    appdelegate.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [appdelegate.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: I didnt declare the tabbarcontroller in my app delegate firstlt I am using a view once i login then I am showing the tabbar

Comment: self.mybaseTabbarController.selectedIndex = 0;
    [self.mybaseTabbarController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: I used the above code in by applicationdidcometoforeground method. It was going to the first tab but the parentview controller is not getting shown. root view controllers were getting shown in that regard

Answer (score 0):

in appdelegate.m file

I'm adding splash view. You should call tabbar object and load it in your view.

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    viewController1=[[splasView alloc]initWithNibName:@"splasView" bundle:nil];
[self.window addSubview:viewController1.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

let me know if any query you have

Comment: nope buddy I guess u got me wrong I am moving on to the first tab but not to the parentviewcontroller of my first tab. I just want to know how to move to the parent view of my first tab